# How do you share request headers in Express.js to a static SPA?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, single-page-application

I have a single-page react application, let's call it `foo`, bundled with webpack, that I am serving statically with Express.js. I need to share a session from another application which is launching `foo`. I am thinking of generating a JSON web token and POSTing to the Express server with the token in the Authorization header.

Currently I pass information from the launch request into the application by setting a cookie with Express and reading the cookie in the application. However I predict there are security flaws with this approach (JWT.io indicates "You also should not store sensitive session data in browser storage due to lack of security."). I don't know how else to pass information to `foo`, since it's not actually an express.js app, it's more like a cross-platform JS app that is now being hosted. So since it is served statically I do not invoke any 'startup' actions from express.

I can see a couple angles towards a solution, but I am not sure which to take.

- Can I expose the request headers to the static react app so that it can securely be read?
- Can I serve the webpack bundle 'non-statically' (dynamically?) from express, and invoke a startup function?

Comment: Any sensitive information that you are passing in cookie is as insecure as passing it through JWT.

Comment: @tbking right, we are on the same page, I don't want to use cookies. I want some more direct way of communicating from express to the SPA

Comment: An API is the way to go. Adding JWT to headers or body or cookie isn't going to make any difference from security point of view.

Comment: @tbking I'm sorry but I don't understand. Do you mean express saves the session data privately, and the SPA requests it? If the SPA hits an API endpoint provided by Express, Express won't know which session data to give it.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I meant there has to be someway to communicate session. It can be JWT in headers, cookie. Both of them will be accessible in client browser. Avoid adding any sensitive information like plain text password, and you should be good.